# Create a year month list of specific intervals in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, date, datetime, time

How could I create a list of date based on the following condition:

For example, today is `2020-07-01`, so I need a list of date contains last month, next 6 month and next 12 month. The expected list will be `[2020-06, 2020-12, 2020-06]`.

Please note I need to use `datetime.today()` to keep the list dynamically changed.

I have obtained the current month by the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

Out:

```
2020-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `relativedelta` to find the diff of the months and a list of the required months.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

need_months = [-1, 6, 12]
print([(datetime.today()+ relativedelta(months=i if i < 0 else i - 1)).strftime('%Y-%m') for i in need_months])
```

Output

```
['2020-06', '2020-12', '2021-06']
```

Comment: If I want to create a list from now to next 3 months, `['2020-07', '2020-08', '2021-09']`, how could I get that?

Comment: Just change the need_months to `need_months = [1, 2, 3]`